# ASP.NET MVC: Shared layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a new empty ASP.NET MVC 4 project, and added a new folder `Shared` in `View` and new file `_Layout.cshtml` and put this code to that

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

and now when I add new view for a controller it doesn't detect it as master page automatically as well as `Basic Template`

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AboutUs";
}

<h2>AboutUs</h2>
```

it doesnt get `_Layout.cshtml` file as master page until I set that manually with `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need a `_ViewStart.cshtml` in your `Views` folder which should have the following in it:

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```